# Mongo returning array of arrays instead of objects

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, php-7.1

I have the following issue. I have just created a new mongodb instance in my aws account with the same version but the results coming from my php queries come in a different way.

Before I used to get an array of objects but now I get and array of arrays.
For example :

**Before:**

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class stdClass#401 (6) {
    public $_id =>
    class MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId#390 (1) {
      public $oid =>
      string(24) "5a685fa82fdc5d031e25451c"
    }
  }
}
```

**Now:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#393 (6) {
    ["_id"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#390 (1) {
      ["oid"]=>
      string(24) "5a685fa82fdc5d031e25451c"
    }
  }
}
```

Before I used to access my variables from php using the arrow like :

```
$document->_id;
```

but now, after getting the results in that way, I need to get change everything to :

```
$document['_id'];
```

Is there any setting (php/mongo server) so I can get the results like previously?

I use the php mongo driver to query my database - e.g :

```
$query = new Query($filter, $options);
/** @var MongoDB\Driver\Manager $manager */
return $manager->executeQuery($collection,$query)->toArray();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the cursor you can specify how it returns the results with [setTypemap](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.settypemap.php). I think `['document' => 'stdClass']` will do the trick:

```
$query = new Query($filter, $options);
/** @var MongoDB\Driver\Manager $manager */
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery($collection, $query);
$cursor->setTypeMap(['document' => 'stdClass']);
return $cursor->toArray();
```

Comment: ->setTypeMap(['root' => 'object']) fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$cursor->setTypeMap(['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array', 'array' => 'array']);

Comment: Found this to be the best answer, you can also specify it as in the options array to the find() and findOne() queries